# Preserve type information in generic functions

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, trpc

I'm trying to chain together input parsers for a procedure in trpc, but because of the type `ProcedureBuilder<any>`, chaining loses information. I've been digging around for the type wizardry, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
import { initTRPC } from '@trpc/server';
import { ProcedureBuilder } from '@trpc/server';
import { z } from 'zod';

const t = initTRPC.create();
export const procedure = t.procedure;

function addAddress(a: ProcedureBuilder<any>) {
    return a.input(z.object({
        address: z.string()
    }))
}

function addPreKey(a: ProcedureBuilder<any>) {
    return a.input(z.object({
        key: z.string()
    }))
}

export const test = addAddress(addPreKey(procedure));
test.query(({ input }) => { input.address; input.key; })
                                                  ^^^ Errors
```

I just can't seem to figure out the type solution, but this works (which is why I think its a type narrowing issue)

```
export const a = procedure.input(
     z.object({
         key: z.string(),
     }) ).input({
     z.object({
         address: z.string(),
     })
 });
```

Comment: Your code that "works" has a syntax error.

Comment: I got it to [this](https://tsplay.dev/we6bVN) but I don't quite know how to get the errors inside the functions to disappear.